# An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

`if (NavigationContext.QueryString["id"] != null)`

An exception of type

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

occurred in `mscorlib.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code

Please help me :(

Comment: The query string doesn't have an "id" key.  Use `ContainsKey` to test for it.  Everything you need to fix this is contained in the exception message.  Try reading it before running for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if(NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id")) //this checks if "QueryString" has the key "id"
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString["id"] != null) //this checks if the key "id" in "QueryString" is null or not 
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Also, if you are checking for a string, better use

```
string id = NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```